# Overriding standard components default values / implementation

Tags: jsf-2

I'm wondering if it's possible to override standard JSF components or Primefaces components without having to have your own namespace for them?

Let's say I have the regular `<h:outputText>` component, and I want to change the default value of the escape attribute. Can I do this without having to create my own component, overriding the outputText and putting `<my:outputText>` everywhere? I would be happy to still use `<h:>`.

Right now I am setting some values in the renderer class since it's easier, but I would prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you just override the Component-Class, you can still use the old tags:

This Example changes the value `foo-bar` to `BAR_FOO`:

*page.xhtml:*

```
<h:outputText value="foo-bar" />
```

*Custom Component Class:*

```
package org.example.myComponents;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText;
public class DefaultOutput extends HtmlOutputText {
    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        Object value = super.getValue();
        if(value != null && value instanceof String) {
            String val = (String) value;
            if(val.equals("foo-bar")) {
                value = "BAR_FOO";
                setValue(value);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

*faces-config.xml*

```
<component> 
    <component-type>javax.faces.HtmlOutputText</component-type> 
    <component-class>org.example.myComponents.DefaultOutput</component-class> 
</component>
```

*output in Browser:*

```
BAR_FOO
```

---

In the Custom Component Class you can override the Methods for those Values you want to give Defaults. 
I used it to set Defaults on `p:calendar`, i also called the setter, since the calculations of my defaults where rather expensive:

```
@Override
public String getPattern() {
    String pattern = (String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.pattern);
    if(pattern == null) {
        pattern = getLocaleBean().getInputDateFormatPattern();
        setPattern(pattern);
    }
    return pattern;
}
```

I din't call `super.getPattern()` since that would give me a  Primefaces-Default-Value in some cases. Instead i accessed `getStateHelper().eval` directly.

---

### How do one Know, what's the component-type and the Class to extend for a specific component-tag?

If you use a PrimefacesCompnents its quite easy, the [Primefaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) 
describes the `Component Type` and `Component Class` for every Component.

If you looking for the Standard Components, the [MyFaces Documentation](http://myfaces.apache.org/core22/myfaces-impl/tagdoc.html) lists  `Component type` and the `UIComponent class` to extend for the standard tags (The `Component type` and the `UIComponent class` are the same for Mojarra, too).

Comment: Hmmm.... From the original question: _"Right now I am setting some values in the renderer class since it's easier, but I would prefer not to do that."_

Comment: You'll have to Extend a Renderer Class and register it just like this Component. I Think the asker meant "easier than a Custom Component with a custom tag (`<my:outputText>`)". With this soultion, he can still use `<h:>`

Comment: Could be, but if the OP knows how to do that, I wonder why the solution you mention was not tried... Lets wait ;-)